# Compare two files and print N lines after the matching word

Tags: linux, perl, awk, grep

I need to search a name from `File1` against `File2`. If the matching name is found, I need to print it together with three lines after it.

**— File1 —**

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

**— File2 —**

```
Topic1 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
Name1 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
Name3 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
Topic2 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
Topic3 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
```

**— Expected result —**

```
Name1 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
Name3 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
```

- I tried to use awk to find matching between two files and only succeeded in printing `Name1 ....description...` (without `lineA` - `lineC`)

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN { while ( getline < "File1" ) arr[$0]++ }( $1 in arr )' File2
  ```
- I know grep command can be used to print certain lines using pattern

  ```
  grep -A3 /pattern/ file
  ```

My problem now is I don't know how to combine these two commands. Perhaps someone can suggest a Perl script to run these flow?

Comment: have you heard of unix pipelines?

Comment: err nope..i'm totally new in this environment

Comment: what about unix shell scripts? bash programming?

Comment: yup..still learning on it..i know the basic format..

Comment: Can I take it that there's always a space after the name in `File 2`?

Comment: owh..sorry...the name should be File1 and File2...very sorry for the mistakes

Comment: @Sue: Thanks, but I meant to ask if there was always a space (or a tab) after the name in lines like `Name1 ....description...`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass grep a file containing patterns (`-f` option), so

```
$ grep -F -f file1 -A3 file2
Name1 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
Name3 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
```

Using `-F` to indicate the patterns are fixed strings, not regular expressions.

Comment: thanks glenn jackman!! the command works perfectly when i try it on local Redhat but when i run it on Redhat server, all content in file2 are printed :( any idea why it is like this?

Comment: Are there any blank lines in file1?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. It reads all of the names from `File1` into a hash, so that the values from `File2` can be quickly checked.

`File2` is read line by line, and the first field checked against the hash to see if it is one of the wanted names. If so, then the current line and the three following lines are printed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my %names;

open my $fh, '<', 'File1';

while ( <$fh> ) {
  chomp;
  ++$names{$_};
}

open $fh, '<', 'File2';

while ( <$fh> ) {
  my ($name) = split;
  if ( $names{$name} ) {
    print;
    print scalar <$fh> for 1 .. 3;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
Name1 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
Name3 ....description...
lineA
lineB
lineC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have used xargs:

```
cat File1 | xargs -I NAME grep -A3 NAME File2
```

The canonical way to look for a NAME in File2 and show the matching line and the three lines after it is:

```
grep -A3 NAME File2
```

The way to generate such a command for each line of File 1, using the line as NAME is:

```
cat File1 | xargs -I NAME <COMMAND with NAME in it>
```